# How do you get the green cap (reds hat)?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I love vanity items, I just need one more : the fabled green cap.

I have tried butchering a few guides named Andrew in Terraria Mobile and none of them dropped it.

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a very early version of ios try killing fire imps. If you are up to date just keep killing Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Guide Voodoo Doll equipped and then killing him with any weapon instead of using butchering. Due to the fact you normally can't kill him without a Voodoo Doll, the game thinks that a mob or other entity killed him because it's normally impossible. By using the Voodoo Doll, the game knows you killed him **on purpose**. It should then drop Redigit's Green Cap!

In a nutshell: Try killing him by using the Guide Voodoo Doll, then attacking him.